# Export SQL query data to Excel and storing location excel outside network

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, t-sql

I have to export the Sql server data into the Excel file and to export data I am using the `sql query` as

```
insert into OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\testing.xls;', 
'SELECT * FROM [SheetName$]') select * from SQLServerTable
```

But In above query I am exporting data into the `D drive` which is local in my system.
What If i have to export data to some other system which is outside my network. That system might exist in some other location or company. If i give shared folder in other system with `System IP Address and location`instead of `D drive` whether it will work or not.
means

```
insert into OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
'Excel 8.0;Database=\\10.10.10.10\ab\A\testing.xls;', 
'SELECT * FROM [SheetName$]') select * from SQLServerTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that user, which excecutes this query can access the file. Also check is file shared or not?

To check is you SQL Server has permition to file excecute

```
EXEC Master.dbo.xp_DirTree '\\10.10.10.10\ab\A\',1,1
```

If result will show you a list of files, SQL server has permition

> To use BULK INSERT or INSERT...SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK...) to
>   bulk import data from another computer, the data file must be shared
>   between the two computers. To specify a shared data file, use its
>   universal naming convention (UNC) name, which takes the general form,
>   \Servername\Sharename\Path\Filename. Additionally, the account used
>   to access the data file must have the permissions that are required
>   for reading the file on the remote disk.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175915.aspx